# Relational Database: Is junction table with a third foreign key still a junction table.. or entity?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, junction-table

I have a junction table (Actor_Character) with a composite key made from the primary keys of two other tables (Actor & Character). Because it's a junction table Actor and Character will also both be foreign keys. Now, if I add a third foreign key (DVD) to this junction table does it become an entity? Normally, if you add a new non-key attribute to a junction table it does become an entity. However,in this case I am not adding a non-key attribute (it's a foreign key) and it's also not really new - A DVD entity already exists elsewhere with DVD_ID as it's primary key.

The overall business problem I'm trying to solve is this:

If a customer has a DVD and knows what actors are in it, how do they find out what character one of those actors plays in the DVD.

My solution is to query these two junction tables (DVD_Actor) & (Actor_Character) in the following way:

```
select char_id from char_actor where actor_id = 1 and dvd_id = 14
```

The problem I have is: How do I represent this on my E.R Diagram? Is it an entity or a junction table?